# C++ Как передать объект, который вызывает метод, в этот метод как параметр?

Tags: c++

[image: Код программы]

У меня есть класс User и класс Project. Нужно, чтобы в методе someUser.createProject(nameProject) вызывался конструктор класса Project с двумя параметрами nameProject и someUser. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Во-первых, дайте текст, а не глазоломный скриншот, во-вторых, дайте хоть какое-то описание ваших классов... Понять из вашего вопроса, что вы хотите, не получается.

Answer (score 0):

`this` - указатель. Раз хотите передать `User`, а не `User *`, то разыменуйте его: `*this`.